# Addition of Alephs

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Prove:
$\aleph_{\alpha}  + \aleph_{\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha} $

The textbook I am using has a long proof done by transfinite induction.  I am looking for a direct proof.

Can I do this:

$\aleph_{\alpha} + \aleph_{\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha} \cdot \aleph_{\alpha}$

$= \text{max} \{\aleph_{\alpha}, \aleph_{\alpha} \}$

$= \aleph_{max \{\alpha,\alpha \} }$

$= \aleph_{\alpha} $

Comment: I'm not an expert here but I think transfinite induction *is* the direct proof. Perhaps you meant a *shorter* one?

Comment: I don't really know a proof that circumvent the inductive argument. Unless of course you already know that $\aleph_\alpha\cdot\aleph_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$. But that usually takes a slightly more complicated induction.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I put up one attempt, the textbook suggests to express $\omega_{\alpha}$ as a disjoint union of two sets of cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha}$

Comment: Sarah, it's hard to say what can be counted as a valid proof if we don't know what you already know or don't know. From a brief look I would have thought that your attempted proof is circular, but if you already know that addition and multiplication equal to taking the larger index, then you're essentially done. On the other hand, the book is right.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Let $\omega_\alpha$ be the least ordinal of cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$. Note that every ordinal can be written as $\delta+n$ where $\delta$ is a limit ordinal. The maps $\delta+n\mapsto\delta+2n$ and $\delta+n\mapsto\delta+2n+1$ are both injections from $\omega_\alpha$ into itself, and their ranges are disjoint.